# Get a count for a pattern using python

Tags: python

In the following how to count the number of times that `__TEXT__` appears in the variable sing python

```
    a="This is __TEXT__ message to test __TEXT__ message"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count occurrence of a character in a Python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-python-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a.count("__TEXT__")`