# What is the preferred way to count the number of ocurrences of a certain character in a string?

Tags: python, string

How do I do this without `string.count()`, because it is listed as deprecated in Python v2.7.3 documentation?

I am unable to find what I should use instead.

EDIT: The question originally stated that `str.count()` was deprecated but that is incorrect and misleading. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385996/966508 for explanation

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake with the question, editing now.

Comment: [It is?](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) - even in [3.2](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) I see no deprecated notes.

Comment: Did you maybe mean `string.count`, which is deprecated (alongside most of the rest of the `string` module)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman That might be it. http://docs.python.org/library/string.html lists it under "deprecated string functions". But if it were the whole module, why aren't they all deprecated?

Comment: @varesa `str` and `string` are different. The former is the type of strings in python, the latter a module that handles string-related things.

Comment: @Lattyware Should the question be edited to "Why is string.count deprecated / how to replace" or left as it is?

Comment: @varesa I think as it stands it's fine, this way at least if someone searches for this, it might come up so they get the explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: @GinoMempin It does answer the headline even though https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385996/966508 gives more context related to the deprecation issue. Also funny that an 8 years old question suddenly came to the surface

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`str.count()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) - it's not listed as deprecated.

([Python 2.7.3](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), [Python 3.2.3](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) - both have no notes about being deprecated).

```
>>> "test".count("t")
2
```

I'll presume you meant [`string.count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.count) - which is depreciated in favour of the method on string objects.

The difference is that `str.count()` is a method on string objects, while `string.count()` is a function in the `string` module.

```
>>> "test".count("t")
2
>>> import string
>>> string.count("test", "t")
2
```

It's clear why the latter has been deprecated (and removed in 3.x) in favour of the former.

Comment: The first time I ran into the "deprecated" designation I was confused too. You need to pay attention to the advice to use string methods instead: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions

Comment: @MarkRansom I was going to look at the "String methods" link in the documentation, but somehow forgot :D

Answer (score 5):

Use [`len()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len):

```
>>> len('abcd')
4
```

Comment: This *was* the right answer to the question, before the OP edited it.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine in 2.7.3

```
>>> strs='aabbccddaa'
>>> strs.count('a')
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using count you can do this:

```
def my_count(my_string, key_char):
    return sum(c == key_char for c in my_string)
```

Result:

```
>>> my_count('acavddgaaa','a')
5
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way can be

`strs.__len__()`

Answer (score -1):

```
sentence = str(input("Write a Sentence: "))
count = 0
for word in sentence:
    if word == " ":
    count = count + 1
print(count+1)
```

Comment: 1) This counts the number of spaces, but the OP was asking for "*count number of ocurrances of certain character*", 2) Technically, it's `for letter in sentence`.