# python: check for lines that have X number of periods '.'

Tags: python

How do you check for lines with N number of periods in them?

```
my_count = 6
indict = open("dictionary.txt").read().splitlines()
for line in indict:
# if line has my_count num of '.':
    print line

dictionary.txt looks like:
A.BAN.DON
A.BOUND
A.BI.DING
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-python-string

Comment: Are there sentences? Do you only count words with periods? What about standalone? What about at the end of sentences?

Answer (score 3):

Use the count function.

```
my_count = 6
indict = open("dictionary.txt").read().splitlines()
for line in indict:
    # if line has my_count num of '.':
    if line.count('.') == my_count:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Or well — look at the way described by @Tyler Ferraro.

The question is how do you define a line in your language? A line must end with a period. So technically a line can only contain 0 or 1 periods depending on who you ask.

If it's contained in `''` like: `'.'` or `""` like ".", then it's a different case and you could use regex.

I am **assuming** your line is like: `A.BAN.DON`

```
for line in indict:
# if line has my_count num of '.':
    for character in line:
        if character is ".":
            dotCount += 1
    print "line: %s has %d periods" % (line, dotCount)
```

And you can arrange the rest of the stuff yourself (like declaring dotCount, etc...)