# Finding percentage of nonempty string

Tags: python

I am trying to write code in Python which finds the percentage of the alphabet in a given string. For example,

`percent("ab", "aabccdef")` should give `[("a", 25), ("b", 13)]` since `'a'` occurs twice in a string of length 8, so its percentage is `round(2 / 8)`, or 25.
Similarly, `'b'` occurs only once. So its percentage is `round(1 / 8)`, or 13.

Here is my code. Can someone help me debug this?

```
def Percent(alpha, string):
   y = [e for e in string if e == alpha]
   x = len(y)
   return (alpha, round((x / len(string) * 100)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close but the key difference is that you need to compute it for each character `c` in `alpha`:

```
def percent(alpha, string):
    results = []
    for c in alpha:
        y = [e for e in string if e == c]
        x = len(y)
        results.append((c, round((float(x) / len(string)*100))))
    return results
```

In your code you're comparing `e == alpha` but `alpha` is a string `ab` and `e` is a single character in the string. This won't give you the results you want.

Furthermore, you need to convert `x` to a `float` if you wish to compute the percentage properly. In Python if you write, e.g., `3 / 4` you'll get `0` instead of `0.75`. To prevent this you need to convert at least one of the arguments to a `float` which can be done by calling `float()`. So you could also write `x / float(len(string)*100)` to ensure you won't get an integer as result.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this, you can use [`str.count`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-python-string) in a list comprehension:

```
>>> alpha = 'ab'
>>> string = 'aabccdef'
>>> [(x, string.count(x)/len(string)) for x in alpha]
[('a', 0.25), ('b', 0.125)]
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a possibility to replace .count(x) with something simpler so that no inbuilt functions are used??

Comment: Well, you could replace `string.count(x)` with `len([s for s in string if s==x])`, but I don't think it is simpler.

Comment: I added a link in the answer, if you want to see what `str.count` does. If you prefer not to use `count`, Simeon's answer is fine.