# counting a specific character in php

Tags: php, string, function, count

I have to count the number of "a's" in the string:

```
$a = "aaa apple";
```

this is my code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("count.txt","w");
$txt = "as a teacher i am addicted to apple";
fwrite($file,$txt);
fclose($file);
$file1 = fopen("count.txt","r");
$arr = substr_count("$file1","a");
echo $arr;
?>
```

however this returns 0.

which php function should i use?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
$arr = substr_count("$file1", "a");
```

instead of

```
$arr = substr_count($txt, $a);
```

Why do you need to write to a file before checking the number of occurrences?

If you want to get the content of the file again, use

```
$file1 = fopen("count.txt","r");
$contents = fread($file1, filesize("count.txt"));
fclose($file1);
$arr = substr_count($contents, $a);
```