# Counting occurence within a string Python

Tags: python, string, count

I am writing a code to count the occurrences of each letter within a string.  I understand that it has been asked and answered [Count occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string?rq=1), however I cannot figure out why it will not count when I use it.

```
def percentLetters(string):
  string = 'A','B'
  print string.count('A')
  print string.count('B')
```

If I was to input `percentLetters('AABB')`, I would anticipate receiving A=2 and B=2 but am having no such luck.  I tried using an `if` statement earlier however it would not print anything at all

```
def percentLetters(string):
string='A','B'
if 'A':
  print string.count('A')
if 'B':
  print string.count('B')
```

This doesn't work either.  Anyone who might have some insight it would be helpful

Comment: You are **replacing** the `string` argument with tuple, so it won't matter what you pass in. And what did you expect `if 'A':` and `if 'B':` to test? Both of those are *always* going to be true.

Comment: What did you add `string = 'A', 'B'` for here, what did you expect it to do? That binds the name `string` to a tuple with two elements, `'A'` and `'B'` (the comma makes that a tuple). Whatever it was bound to before (when calling the function) is now no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reassign `string` inside the function and better to not use `string` as a variable name at all.

```
def percentLetters(s):
        print s.count('A')
        print s.count('B')
percentLetters('AABB')
2
2
```

`string = 'A','B'` means you set the string variable to a tuple containing just `("A","B")`, it is not pointing to the `string` you pass in.

```
In [19]: string = 'A','B'

In [20]: string
Out[20]: ('A', 'B')
```

Comment: Ohhh so the tuple, being a list, doesn't allow the code to operate as a string? It is not recognizing or pulling out the individual parts?

Comment: If you want to get the count of the string passed in just call count on the string, setting string = "A","B" means the variable you passed is never used as you reassign the name to your tuplr

Answer (score 1):

Because count is a method/module (whatever it's called in python) for string, the way you do it,

```
myString ='A','B'
```

myString is a tuple, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

first, here is the correct version of your code:

```
def percentLetters(string):      
    print string.count('A')  
    print string.count('B')
```

second, you don't use two strings in an assignment to one variable unless you want to make it a string tuple.