# How to count lines in multi lined strings

Tags: python-3.x

```
Level ="""
            aaaaaa
            awawa"""
```

I'm wondering how do you count the lines of a multi lined string in python.

Also once you've counted those lines how do you count how many letters are in that line. I'd assume to do this part you'd do `len(line_of_string)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's define this multi-line string:

```
>>> level="""one
... two
... three"""
```

To count the number of lines in it:

```
>>> len(level.split('\n'))
3
```

To find the length of each of those lines:

```
>>> [len(line) for line in level.split('\n')]
[3, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 24):

You can count the number of the new-line character occurrences:

```
Level.count('\n') # in your example, this would return `2`
```

and add `1` to the result.

Comment: So in my scenario what would level.count('\n') return

Answer (score 2):

See [Count occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string) for the answer on how to count any character, including a new line. For your example, Level.count('\n') and add one.

I'd suggest then splitting on the new line and getting lengths of each string, but there are undoubtedly other ways:

lineList = Level.split('\n')

Then you can get the length of each using len for each item in the list.