# Find how many lines in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a python movie player/maker, and I want to find the number of lines in a multiple line string. I was wondering if there was any built in function or function I could code to do this:

```
x = """
line1
line2 """

getLines(x)
```

Comment: And in this case, the output should be 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count lines in multi lined strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802417/how-to-count-lines-in-multi-lined-strings)

Comment: ```
x.count(os.linesep)+1
```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821784/whats-the-difference-between-n-and-r-n

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If newline is `'\n'` then `nlines = x.count('\n')`.

The advantage is that you don't need to create an unnecessary list as `.split('\n')` does (the result may differ depending on `x.endswith('\n')`).

[`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) accepts more characters as newlines: `nlines = len(x.splitlines())`.

Comment: `str.splitlines()` also won't include the final line break/empty line (if any), which is often the preferred behavior. Example: `text = """line1
line2
{empty line}"""
print(text.split('\n'))
print(text.splitlines())`
Result: `['line1', 'line2', '']
['line1', 'line2']`

Answer (score 15):

You can `split()` it and find the length of the resulting `list`:

```
length = len(x.split('\n'))
```

Or you can `count()` the number of newline characters:

```
length = x.count('\n')
```

Or you can use `splitlines()` and find the length of the resulting `list`:

```
length = len(x.splitlines())
```

Answer (score 9):

`SPAM\nEGGS\nBEANS` = Three lines, two line breaks

So if counting lines, use *+ 1*, or you'll make a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error):

```
x.count( "\n" ) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
len(x.split('\n'))
```