# Finding words in a string

Tags: python, string, list, append

Searched for this but all answers were beyond my scope since I am still learning. I am trying to find number of occurrences of a word within a string. I came up with the following code but keep getting weird answers.

```
s = 'bobzbobz'


word = 'bob'



index = 0 
instance = []
while index < len(s):
    instance.append(s.find(word,index))
    index += 1
print len(instance) #instance = [0, 4, 4, 4, 4, -1, -1, -1]???? Why??
```

This should print 2 but I get 8. And the reason is because I get a lot of repeat values in my list of instances.

Comment: If that's all you want, `s.count(word)` will do it for you :-)

Comment: You get -1's added because when the substring is not found find returns -1, you keep getting 4's because you keep finding the last bob as you only move the index one place

Comment: To see what's going wrong with your code, consider what happens when `index` is 1...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count occurrence of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: @alexis, count does not work for overlapping strings

Comment: Right, good point...

Answer (score 0):

There are much better ways but in your code you need to check for when find returns `-1` for a non match and increase index by what find returns when you do get a match, you are always appending regardless and only moving one index so if there is a later match you keep finding the same substring start index:

```
s = 'bobobzbobz'
word = 'bob'

index = 0
instance = []
while index < len(s) - len(word):
    f = s.find(word, index)
    if f != -1:
        instance.append(f)
        index = f
    index += 1
print (instance)
[0, 2, 6]
```

You cannot use `.count` when you want to consider overlapping substrings as in the example above.

To break it down per iteration using `s = 'bobzbobz'`:

```
s.find(word, 0) -> 0  # s[index:] -> 'bobzbobz' 
s.find(word, 1) -> 4  # s[index:] ->  'obzbobz'
s.find(word, 2) -> 4  # s[index:] ->  'bzbobz'
s.find(word, 3) -> 4  # s[index:] -> 'zbobz'
s.find(word, 4) -> 4 # s[index:] -> 'bobz'
s.find(word, 5) -> -1 # s[index:] -> 'obz'
s.find(word, 6) -> -1 # s[index:] ->  'bz'
s.find(word, 7) -> -1 # s[index:] ->  'z'
```

You get four 4's in your output list as from index 1 to index 4 find is finding the substring word starting at index 4, after that the index has moved past the last bob i.e index 4 so you get -1 added each time as find does not find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `find` will scan the rest of the string, looking for occurrences that start further down. So you keep matching the same occurrence of `bob` until you advance past it. To check each position exactly once, use a different method. One possibility is simply using `startswith()`:

```
n = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:].startswith("bob"):
        n += 1
```

Or equivalently:

```
n = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s.startswith("bob", i):
        n += 1
```

There are all sorts of alternatives to using a loop, but I think this is nice and clear.

Answer (score -1):

```
s = 'bobzbobz'
word = 'bob'
print s.count(word)
```