# counting the number of vowels in a word in a string

Tags: python, string, count

I am a beginner, and I am trying to find out the number of vowels in each word in a string. So for instance, if I had `"Hello there WORLD"`, I want to get an output of `[2, 2, 1]`.

Oh, and I am using Python.

I have this so far

```
[S.count(x) in (S.split()) if x is 'AEIOUaeiou']
```

where `S="Hello there WORLD"`

but it keeps saying error. Any hints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count occurrence of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: What hasn't worked for you so far?

Comment: `[sum(1 for char in word if char.lower() in set('aeiou')) for word in string.split()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, S in S.count and S in S.split cannot be the same S. I suggest using more semantic names.

```
>>> phrase = 'Hello there WORLD'
>>> [sum(letter.casefold() in 'aeiouy' for letter in word) for word in phrase.split()]
[2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x is 'AEIOUaeiou'
```

This tests whether `x` is precisely the same object as `'AEIOUaeiou'`. This is almost never what you want when you compare objects. e.g. the following could be `False`:

```
>>> a = 'Nikki'
>>> b = 'Nikki'
>>> a is b
False
```

Although, it may be `True` as sometimes Python will optimise identical strings to actually use the same object.

```
>>> a == b
True
```

This will always be `True` as the *values* are compared rather than the *identity* of the objects.

What you probably want is:

```
x in 'AEIOUaeiou'
```