# How to get this type of output in python in string

Tags: python, string

How to get this type of  output in python?

Input: `'PythoN Is AwoSoMe'`

Output: `'aWOsOmE iS pYTHOn'`

Help me to solve that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [better way to invert case of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385823/better-way-to-invert-case-of-string)/[Swapping uppercase and lowercase in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247173/4518341) and [How to reverse the order of the words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34128842/4518341)

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577) What have you tried?

Comment: Swapcase is done but how to write 3 words as 1st words and 1st words as 3rd word

Comment: Did you even take a look of the first comment?@user12498867 It says how to reverse the string and also the use of swapcase. The soltution it's literally there.

Comment: @MrNobody TBF I edited it after posting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `swapcase()` to swap the cases, `split()` to divide the string into a list of words, `reversed()` to reverse the order of the words, and `join()` to join the list of words back into a single string.

```
>>> 'PythoN Is AwoSoMe'.swapcase()
'pYTHOn iS aWOsOmE'
>>> 'PythoN Is AwoSoMe'.swapcase().split()
['pYTHOn', 'iS', 'aWOsOmE']
>>> list(reversed('PythoN Is AwoSoMe'.swapcase().split()))
['aWOsOmE', 'iS', 'pYTHOn']
>>> ' '.join(reversed('PythoN Is AwoSoMe'.swapcase().split()))
'aWOsOmE iS pYTHOn'
```