# compute character frequencies in Python strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-3.5

I was wondering if there is a way in Python 3.5 to check if a string contains a certain symbol.  Also I'd like to know if there is a way to check the amount the string contains. For example, if I want to check how many times the character '$' appears in this string... 
`^$@%#$$`,
 how would I do that?

Comment: have you try using regex?

Comment: Possibly duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the built-in functions **index** and **count**.  You can find full documentation at the [official site](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).  Please get used to doing the research on your own; the first step is to get familiar with the names of the language elements.

```
if my_str.index('$') != 0:
    # Found a dollar sign

print my_str.count('$')
```

Comment: Thanks I will do more research on it!

Comment: or `'$' in my_str` -- Which is a more idiomatic way to check for a substring in a string...

Comment: I looked into using '$' in my_str but I like the other better... @mgilson

Comment: `if '$' in my_str:` is a better choice. As what you are doing is assuming the character is already in the string (Returns an error if not found). Additionally, If you have the string `'$Hello$'` the if statement won't return `True` for any string starting with the character.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**`split`**](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to check if symbol's in the string:

```
if your_str.split('$'):
    print(your_str.count('$'))
```

You can also use [**`re.findall`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
print(len(re.findall('\$', your_str)))
```

It returns `0` if there is no such a symbol in the string, otherwise returns count of that symbol in the string.

But the easiest way is to check and return **`count`** if symbol is in:

```
print(your_str.count('$'))
```

It returns `0` if nothing is found.

Comment: "re.findall" sounds like an interesting way to do this that I have not seen yet i will look into it. Thank you!

Comment: Good thing about findall that you can search for a pattern, not just for a symbol

Comment: That might be helpful in the future if i decide to head down that road.

Comment: Why would you use `split` to check if a symbol is in the string?  That's quite a round-about way to think of it (not to mention inefficient).  Also, regex for this simple problem also seems overkill . . . `'$' in your_str` is the best way to check if a substring exists in a string. . . If you need the index where it occures, then I suppose `index = your_str.find('$')` would be the suggested method. . .

Comment: yes find/index or just if symbol in string would work just fine, but they are already covered in other answer/comments. So i just added couple other alternative ways, findall is good when you search for a pattern, that's why i mentioned it and split is just a short, i agree that find will work faster, because it'll stop after the first occurance