# Python Count the number of periods (.) there are in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Count the number of periods (.) there are in the file.

Use the built-in function `count()` on the file after you have converted it
to a string.

Answer with the result as an integer.

I've no idea to do this..please help!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count

Comment: the description of what you need to do is straightforward, `open` the file, `read` it and `count('.')` the dots.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string I believe the answer to the question can help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try as follow

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    file_content = f.read()

result = file_content.count('.')
```

`result` will be the number of periods.

Comment: Thanks alot!!!! I love you

Comment: you're welcome. if it works confirm the answer

Comment: My answer was 5199

Comment: i mean... you have to check the answer with the check symbol at the left of my answer

Comment: Haha thanks.. I just did. Im new to this sorry!

Comment: Not to be that guy but don't you mean periods, not commas?

Comment: sorry! my fault :)