# string index out of range error in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that searches a string for 'bob' and prints the amount of times it appears.
Here is the code:

```
s = 'mbobobboobooboo'
numbob = 0
for i in range(len(s) ) :
    u = s[i] 
    if u == 'o':
        g = i
        if g != 0 and g != len(s) :
            if (s[g+1]) == 'b' and (s[g-1]) == 'b': #this line is the problam
                numbob += 1
                print("Number of times bob occurs is: " +str(numbob) )
```

I am getting the string index out of range error and i cant seem to fix it. any suggestions

Comment: Are you looking for s.count('bob') ?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string

Which provides a much nicer way to do what you're doing. :)

Comment: Note that `'bobob'.count('bob') == 1`, not 2 as one might hope.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
for i in range(len(s)-1)
```

or

```
g!=len(s)-1
```

`len()` gives you the total number of characters, which will be the index of the character after the last one since indexing starts at 0.

You can get rid of the `if g!=0 and g!=len(s)` part all together if you use

```
for i in range(1,len(s)-1)
```

Comment: it worked! thank you for the quick answer, i can't stress that enough

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Thanks for the edit. It looks much nicer now. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you make your condition :

```
if (s[g+1]) == 'b' and (s[g-1]) == 'b':
```

At the last element of your string, it is impossible to do `s[g+1]` because it is out of the string.

So you have to finish your loop just before the end. Like this for exemple :

```
for i in range(len(s)-1) :
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution would more easy than your. instead of divide letters 'b' 'o' 'b' . slice string **s**

```
countbob=0
bob='bob'
for i in range(len(s)):
       bob2=s[i:i+3]
       if bob2 == bob:
               countbob +=1
print ("Number of times bob occurs is: " + str(countbob))
```