# Write string to file with different byte size?

Tags: python, file

I am doing a Python scripting.

I have a string, the `len()` of the string is `1048576` and the `sys.getsizeof()` of the string is `1048597`.

However, when I write this string to a file, the byte size of the file is `1051027`. My code is below, anyone can tell me why the byte size of file is different with that of the string?

```
print type(allInOne) # allInOne is my string
print len(allInOne)
print sys.getsizeof(allInOne)
newFile = open("./all_in_one7.raw", "w")
newFile.write(allInOne.encode('ascii'))
newFile.close()
```

---

My string is `allInOne`, it is generated with many processes before, it was generated like this `allInOne = numpy.uint8(dataset.pixel_array).tostring()` , above this, `dataset.pixel_array` is of type `numpy.ndarray`. I don't know whether this info would be of any help.

Comment: overhead from the file type etc

Comment: @kaminsknator but if i write a simple string like "abcd" to the same file type, the `len` of the string is exactly the same with the byte size of the string.

Comment: What is `len(allInOne.encode('ascii'))`?  Which filesystem type are you writing to?

Comment: @cdarke this len is the same as the origin len

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski , thanks sir, but my problem is the difference between `size of file` and `len of string`... and how to solve it

Comment: Oops, I've misread question. Not a dupe, upvoted answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `allInOne = numpy.uint8(dataset.pixel_array).tostring()` doesn't look like text. When writing anything but text to a file in Python, you need to [open the file in binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) (`"wb"` instead of `"w"`) so that Python doesn't assume the `0x0A` bytes are `'\n'` line endings and attempt to convert them to the `'\r\n'` line endings that are more common on Microsoft Windows.

To see if this is your problem, [count that particular character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1155617/2738262):

```
print len(allInOne), "bytes"
print len(allInOne) + allInOne.count('\n'), "bytes with 0A counted twice"
```