# Finding most common letter in a word list

Tags: python

I am writing a code for the game hangman. I am stuck in the part where I want to help the user to get a hint.

I need to create a function that accepts a `word list`, and the current `pattern`(for example:"___e_") and returns the `most common letter` in the word list.

I know I need to count the letters in each word and then return the maximum of that letter list but I don't quite know how to actually perform this.

**I started by writing this code:**

```
def choose_letter(words, pattern):
    new_list = [0] * 26
    for i in range(0, 26):
        for n in range(0, len(num_list)):
            if i == num_list[n]:
                new_list[i] += 1

    return new_list
```

but I get stuck because I don't know how to actually compare it to a letter.

I would love to hear some advice or guidance that will help me proceed.

*we didnt learn about dictionary yet

Comment: @MooingRawr That's what this site is for...

Comment: Are you allowed to use `set` ?

Comment: yes we learned about it this week so i think so

Answer (score 2):

you can also use Counter from collections

```
from collections import Counter
Counter('abracadabra').most_common(3)


output: 
[('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: thanks Shivkumar but i cant use counter .. is there a different way to solve this without using counter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `count` and `set` to run the most frequent letter that is not contained in `pattern`, see below. The first line counts the number of occurrence for each letter, the second statement returns (one of) the most frequent letter(s).

```
def choose_letter(words, pattern):
    frequencies = [(letter, words.count(letter)) for letter in set(words) if letter not in pattern and letter!=' ']
    most_frequent_letter = max(frequencies, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
    return most_frequent_letter


word = 'hangman is great fun'
pattern = '____a_____'
print choose_letter(word,pattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> data = "Harsha Biyani"
>>> d = {}
>>> letters = set(data)
>>> for letter in letters :
    d[letter] = data.count(letter)


>>> key, value = max(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])  #in python 3
>>> key, value = max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])  # in python 2
>>> key
'a'
>>> value
3
>>> d
{'y': 1, 'H': 1, 'h': 1, ' ': 1, 'n': 1, 'B': 1, 's': 1, 'a': 3, 'i': 2, 'r': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method count() of a string to count the occurence of a char in a string : [Count occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to use a dictionary with the letters as keys. You can also use ord(char) to get an integer from a character, and use that integer as index for your list.
Because your list is length 26 and the index for letters start at 97 (for lowercase 'a'), you can do something like:

```
def choose_letter(words, pattern): 
    new_list = [0] * 26
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        for letter in word:
            index = ord(letter) -97
            new_list[index] += 1
    return new_list
```

To get the count for any given letter on the list you can:

```
print(new_list[ord(letter)])
```

To get the most common letter (note that if multiple letters have the highest value, only the first one will be returned):

```
chr(new_list.index(max(new_list)))
```

Comment: Thanks! it did give me a list woth a length of 26  but now when ii want to find the letter how do i go back?

Comment: @Adamso Can you edit your question including which letter you want and how to get it? It is not clear. I will add how to get the count for any letter on the list to my answer.

Comment: sure. for example:  for the list:"grape, tree, tomato" it should return the letter "e".

Comment: @Adamso Added to answer

Comment: thanks so much Martín Basterrechea! for a strange reason the output i get is none