# Encoding a string with Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve a programming question to convert a string to below form:
input: `aaaabbbcc`
output: `a4b3c2`

My code is like below:

```
def encode(s):
    output = []
    i = 0
    j = 1
    while i < len(s) and j < len(s)-1 :
        count = 1
        output.append(s[j])


    while s[i] == s[j] :
        count += 1
        j+=1
        i+=1

    output.append(count)
    i += 1
    j += 1


new_s = "".join(str(x) for x in output)
return new_s
```

But I am getting the below exception :
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "encode.py", line 30, in 
>   print encode(s)
>   File "encode.py", line 13, in encode
>   while s[i] == s[j] :
>   IndexError: string index out of range

I am not able to understand the bug here. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You're not checking for j going out of bounds inside the inner loop...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Yes, thanks got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function:

```
import itertools
result = ""
for k, group in itertools.groupby('aaaabbbcc'):
    result += '%s%d' % (k, len(list(group)))
print(result)
>>> a4b3c2
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated you are not checking the list bounds in the inner loop.

Note that you can do the string conversion with a regular expression (`import re`) and list comprehension, like this:

```
''.join([ch + str(len(m)) for m, ch in re.findall(r"((.)\2*)", "aaaabbbcc")])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine.The only issue being if string has a single letter like `aaabbd` `d1` will not come back.
You can try with `re` as well.

```
x="aaaabbbccd"
print "".join([j+str(len(i)) for i, j in re.findall(r"((.)\2*)", x)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [collections Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

in_str = "aaaabbbccd"
out_str = ""
letters = Counter(in_str)

for l in letters:
    out_str += l + str(letters[l])

print(out_str) # a4b3c2d1
# Note: in_str of "aabaa" will produce out_str of "a4b1"
```

Comment: Note that this will not work for repeated groups, like `aaabaa`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `string` into `set`. Than you can iterate the `set` and call the `count()` for finding number of repetition character.

```
input_str = 'aaaabbbcc'
# converting into set
input_set=set(list(input_str))
for i in input_set:
    print(i+str(input_str.count(i)),end='')
# as set is unordered so output will come unordered.
```