# How to see if element is in my list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find out if there is an way to see how many of an object (count) from one list is in another list.

I have a class Card.

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.number == other.number

    def getNumber(self, card):
        return card.number
```

I have a class Deck which contains a list of Cards.

```
class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for i in range(11):
            for j in range(i):
                self.cards.append(Card(i))
```

I want to see if a I can get the count of a Card in the Deck.

```
deck = Deck()
The deck contains 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 

cards = [Card(6), Card(5), Card(3)]
The cards are 6 5 3
```

I want to know how many 6's, 5's and 3's there are in the deck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string

Comment: I tried this and it works for how many 6's, 5's and 3's there are in the deck.

for card in cards:
        print(deck.cards.count(card))

The result is: 
6
5
3

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tally an individual card, use [*list.count()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

```
for card in cards:
    print(deck.cards.count(card))
```

To tally them all, use [*collections.Counter()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(deck.cards)
Counter({Card(10): 10, Card(9): 9, Card(8): 8, Card(7): 7,
         Card(6): 6, Card(5): 5, Card(4): 4, Card(3): 3,
         Card(2): 2, Card(1): 1})
```

For the counter to work, you'll need to make minor modifications to your *Card* class by adding *__hash__()* and *__repr__()* methods:

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.number == other.number

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.number)

    def getNumber(self, card):
        return card.number

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Card(%r)' % self.number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
print "Count for 6's: ", ListName.count(6)
```

Similarly for 5 and 3:

```
print "Count for 5's: ", ListName.count(5)
print "Count for 3's: ", ListName.count(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try in this way

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> deck1
['1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', 
'6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '8', '8', 
'8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', 
'10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10']
>>> Counter(deck1)
Counter({'10': 10, '9': 9, '8': 8, '7': 7, '6': 6, '5': 5, '4': 4, '3': 3, 
'2': 2, '1': 1})
```