# Counting the occurrence of a character of an input string in python 3.6

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, count

I need to take a string input and count the occurrence of a character only once per character(should not repeat for the same character) and print it in a list or set or tuple. But I'm not getting the desired result.

Code:

```
string1 = input('Enter your string: ')


for letter in string1:

    string2 = string1.count(letter,0)

    ss = str(string2)

    print(ss)
```

Output:

```
Enter your string: ggddg
3
3
2
2
3
```

Comment: And what is the desired output?

Comment: Explain more precisely what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the number occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: It should print the number of occurrences of a letter only once and should print all of them in a list or tuple or set @OlivierMelançon

Comment: @MaeshHedge when asked about the desired output, please add it as answer so everyone who sens the question has access to it. Thanks

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Apologies, I will keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the count for each different character as many times as they appear in the string. First is `g`, there are 3 `g`s so you print 3, then another `g` comes and you count and print again. I think you want to print that there are 3 'g' and 2 'd'.

Try this:

```
letters = {}
for c in input("Enter your string: "):
    if c not in letters:
        letters[c] = 1
    else:
        letters[c] += 1

print(letters)
```

Output:

```
Enter your string: ggddg
{'g': 3, 'd': 2}
```

Comment: Most Understandable answer! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you want your output to look, you can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which has a dict-like interface:

```
from collections import Counter

user_input = input('Enter your string: ')
counts = Counter(user_input)

print(counts)  # prints: Counter({'g': 3, 'd': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string1 = input('Enter your string: ')
print('\n'.join(list(set([i+' '+str(string1.count(i)) for i in string1]))))
```

Output:

```
Enter your string: aaabbcca
c 2
a 4
b 2
```

Or try this:

```
string1 = input('Enter your string: ')
print('\n'.join(list(set(map(lambda x: x+' '+str(string1.count(x)),string1)))))
```

Output:

```
Enter your string: aaabbcca
c 2
a 4
b 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a dict to storage that info

```
d = {} 

for c in string1:
    try:
        d[c] += 1
    except KeyError:
        d[c] = 1
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, try it with the sample user string

```
#!python3

# sample user string: fdshjkfdskhjlfdsjklfdsevcxzm,.czxm,.

user_string = input('Enter your string: ')

all_letters = []
unique_letters = []

for letter in user_string:
    all_letters.append(letter)

for unique in all_letters:
    if unique in unique_letters:
        pass
    else:
        unique_letters.append(unique)

for item in unique_letters:
    print(item + ' = ' + str(all_letters.count(item)))

# results
'''
f = 4
d = 4
s = 4
h = 2
j = 3
k = 3
l = 2
e = 1
v = 1
c = 2
x = 2
z = 2
m = 2
, = 2
. = 2
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Mahesh**, counting occurrences of a character in a string can be efficiently done by using `set` and `dictionary` as follows.

> Try it online at http://rextester.com/KQV63040.
>
> **Note:** I have used `json` module to pretty print the dictionary.
>
> You can use `OrderedDict` of `collections` module to retain the order of keys in dictionary based on insertion.

```
import json

string1 = input('Enter your string: ').strip()

unique_letters = set(string1)
letters_occurrences = {}

for letter in unique_letters:
    letters_occurrences[letter] = string1.count(letter)

print() # newline

# Pretty printing the dictionary
print(json.dumps(letters_occurrences, indent=4))
```

» Output

```
Enter your string: abbacddabbc

{
    "b": 4,
    "a": 3,
    "d": 2,
    "c": 2
}
```