# Parsing a file containing filenames and ignoring entries with multiple dot characters?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a file that contains a bunch of filenames, i.e.:

```
hello.txt  
goodbye.py  
test..pdf  
n3w.world.file.text
...
```

I am trying to ignore all filenames with multiple dots.
Currently I am able to find all the filenames using:

```py
import re
data = ['hello.txt', 'goodbye.py', 'test..pdf', 'n3w.world.file.text']
matches = re.findall('([\w].+)\.(\w+)', data)
print(matches)
```

However this prints out all the filenames. How can I modify this to just print out: `hello.txt` and `goodbye.py`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Regex in this case is overkill. You can use `str.count()` function:

```
data = ['hello.txt', 'goodbye.py', 'test..pdf', 'n3w.world.file.text']

data = [w for w in data if w.count('.') < 2]
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
['hello.txt', 'goodbye.py']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   data = [i for i in data if '..' not in i]
```

You can use the above code

Comment: This *would* be a great answer if the question was to ignore filenames with multiple *consecutive* dots. However, it doesn't mention that, and the provided example data indicates otherwise: your solution also includes 'n3w.world.file.text', which is not correct according to the criteria in the question. So, the solution of Andrej is more accurate.