# Finding exact number of characters in word

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to find words with the exact number of the given character.

For example:
If we have this input: `['teststring1','strringrr','wow','strarirngr']` and we are looking for 4 `r` characters
It will return only `['strringrr','strarirngr']` because they are the words with 4 letters `r` in it.

I decided to use regex and read the documentation and I can't find a function that satisfies my needs.
I tried with `[r{4}]` but it apparently returns any word with letters r in it. 
Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) to count the occurrences of a character, combined with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list:

```
myArray =  ['teststring1','strringrr','wow','strarirngr']

letter = "r"
amount = 4

filtered = [item for item in myArray if item.count(letter) == amount]
print(filtered) # ['strringrr', 'strarirngr']
```

If you wanted to make this reusable (to look for different letters or different amounts), you could pack it into a function:

```
def filterList(stringList, pattern, occurrences):
    return [item for item in stringList if item.count(pattern)==occurrences]


myArray =  ['teststring1','strringrr','wow','strarirngr']
letter = "r"
amount = 4

print(filterList(myArray, letter, amount)) # ['strringrr', 'strarirngr']
```

Comment: your algorithm will work only for special case, I mean only for letter `r`, but how you are going to handle case of `t` letter and any other letters?

Comment: and start this function for each letter? I think it's not optimal algorithm

Comment: OP wants "a way to find words with the exact number of the given character". The given code does that.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
import collections

def map_characters(string):
    characters = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for char in string:
        characters[char] += 1
    return characters



items = ['teststring1','strringrr','wow','strarirngr']

for item in items:
    characters_map = map_characters(item)
    # if any of string has 4 identical letters
    # we print it
    if max(characters_map.values()) >= 4:
        print(item)

# in the result it outputs strringrr and strarirngr
# because these words have 4 r letters
```

Comment: What would be the print out of this? Couldn't you map to a dictionary?

Comment: it's just an example, you can do anything you want with it

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets are for matching any items in the set, e.g. `[abc]` matches any words with a,b or c. In your case, it evaluates to `[rrrr]`, so any one r is a match. Try it without the brackets: r{4}

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about using regex, you could use the following:

```
import re
l = ['teststring1', 'strringrr', 'wow', 'strarirngr']
[ word for word in l if re.match(r'(.*r.*){4}', word) ]
```

output: ['strringrr', 'strarirngr']