# Python: Counting amount of D's in a sentence, returns AttributeError message

Tags: python

I'm kind of stuck on this challenge

the objective is:
"Create a function that counts how many D's are in a sentence."

Some examples:

```
count_d("My friend Dylan got distracted in school.") ➞ 4

count_d("Debris was scattered all over the yard.") ➞ 3

count_d("The rodents hibernated in their den.") ➞ 3
```

Here's my current code:

```
def count_d(sentence):
    print(sentence)
    sentence = sentence.lower
    substring = "d"
    return sentence.count(substring)
```

When I run it, the console sends an error message:

```
ERROR: Traceback:
   in <module>
   in count_d
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Comment: `sentence = sentence.lower()` call the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lower() instead of lower only. You want the method to return the value, not to get the method itself

Answer (score 0):

As already note you need to call method not get method itself. I want to add that you might chain `str` methods i.e.:

```
def count_d(sentence):
    print(sentence)
    substring = "d"
    return sentence.lower().count(substring)
```

Depending on situation this might be more readable than doing one action per one line.