# Count occurrences of string in a single cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to count the number of occurances of a string within a single cell in Google Sheets.

If I have

```
599^612
600
601^602^604
44^56^71^83^95^107^119^131^402^451^466^478^490^502^514^571^633^648^661^680^746^813^878^945^1010^1069^1100^1131^1161^1226^1247^1258
```

I would like to get the counts of ^ in each row.

```
Cell | Count
599^612 | 2
600 | 1
601^602^604 | 3
44^56^71^83^95^107^119^131^402 | 9
```

I have tried find, count and countif but can't work it out. Also reviewed [Count the number occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string) but need a solution in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `44^56^71^83^95^107^119^131^402^451^466^478^490^502^514^571^633^648^661^680^746^813^878^945^1010^1069^1100^1131^1161^1226^1247^1258` cuts off at `44^56^71^83^95^107^119^131^402`, but you could count `^` like this:

`=arrayformula({A1:A,if(A1:A<>"",iferror(len(regexreplace(A1:A,"[^\^]",""))+1,),)})`

[image]

Or just the count:

`=arrayformula(if(A1:A<>"",iferror(len(regexreplace(A1:A,"[^\^]",""))+1,),))`

Comment: Works well but when I modify it to fit in my structure as `=arrayformula({M2:M,if(M2:M<>"",iferror(len(M2:M)-len(regexreplace(M2:M,"\^","")),)+1,)})` I get the values in column M repeated before the sum value is put into the next column. Apart from hiding this column is there any way to get it not to show?

Comment: If you only want col2, you can remove `M2:M,` from within the `{}`: `=arrayformula({if(M2:M<>"",iferror(len(M2:M)-len(regexreplace(M2:M,"\^","")),)+1,)})`

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be done using the `LEN` and `SUBSTITUTE` functions.

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "^", ""))+1
```

Comment: Seems to give a value of 1 if there are no occurrences of that character. In scenarios where that is possible, you would need to add a test for no occurrences - perhaps something like iferror(find("^", etc.

Comment: @norie that's a genius idea, I will use it from now on. I edited the response to: 1. make it generic for any separator, 2. remove the _"+1"_ it wasn't needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think I have shorter/simpler than the other solutions.

```
=counta(split(A1,"^"))-1
```

There are a few limitations (like it only works with single characters and also requires the string to never end or start with that character).

But it works for the 4 examples in the question.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,LEN(REGEXREPLACE(""&A1:A, "[0-9]", ))+1))
```

[image]