# How to make definition that counts "e" in a word

Tags: python

I am trying to count the numbers of "e" in a word without using count.(). I made a definition but it outputs this:

```
0
1
1
2
```

How do I make it output just 2 ?

```
def letter_e(word):
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "e" :
            count += 1 
        print(count)

letter_e("fefe")
```

Comment: Don't print inside the loop? Better yet don't print inside the _function_, return the count so you can reuse the functionality elsewhere.

Comment: You can also do `def letter_e(word): return sum(sym == 'e' for sym in word)`, it doesn't use `.count()` method and is shorter and faster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hello! Thanks for your help. I switched print with return, but the value that it outputs is now 0

Comment: I guess you're returning inside the loop then. That doesn't make sense, a function can only return once and you don't want to return on the first character.

Comment: @jonrsharp it works ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: You could use split:  `return len(word.split('e'))-1`

Comment: Or sum: `return sum(c=='e' for c in word)`

Answer (score 1):

As your print statement is within your for loop, every time an "e" is found within the string your count variable is printed.

If you only want to print the final answer, print your count variable outside your for loop.

The code would look like this:

```
def letter_e(word):
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter == "e" :
            count += 1 
    print(count)

letter_e("fefe")
```