# How do I count the character in a string

Tags: python, string, char

I want to count how many characters are there in a string but not occurences. For example:

```
test_list=("aabbccddee")
```

I want the result to be 5 because there are 5 characters:

```
(a,b,c,d,e)
```

I tried using len function and count and also

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Does this solve your problem?

```
from collections import Counter

given_string = "aabbccddee"
result = Counter(given_string)
print(len(result))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `set` in python.

```py
len(set("aabbccddee"))
# returns 5
```

‍`set`s in Python do not contain repeated members (nor are they ordered) like sets in math. Another syntax to define a `set` is like a dictionary without keys:

```py
set_example = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 }
# set_example is { 1, 2, 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
your_str = 'aabbccddee'

result = len(set(your_str))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `set()`:

```
len(dict.fromkeys(test_list))
#5
```