# Single Character Count in Python

Tags: python

This is my first computer related class EVER. We're on week 2, chapter 2 and I need to:

"Write a program whose input is a string which contains a character and a phrase and whose output indicates the number of times the character appears in the phrase."

Really simple, right? Well, i can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my program. I've separated out the part I think is the problem:

```
user_string = input()
user_character = user_string[0][0]

times = user_string.count('user_character') # problem line #

print(user_string)
print(user_character)
print(times)
```

input:

```
t Just trying to find all the ts.
```

expected output:

```
t Just trying to find all the ts.
t
5
```

actual output:

```
t Just trying to find all the ts.
t
0 <<< Why 0?
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes around `user_character`. (Also `[0][0]` is the same as `[0]` in this case, but it's not the cause of the problem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.count()` takes string as an argument (Ref: [docs link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)), which you are providing.

However you are providing a literal string `'user_character'`, what you need to pass is the variable `user_character` (without single quotes) who's value changes as per your input string.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yeah, I don't know what I was thinking... such an obvious mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Removing `'` from `'user_character'` in third line will work

```
user_string = input()
user_character = user_string[0][0]

times = user_string.count(user_character) # problem line #

print(user_string)
print(user_character)
print(times)
```

Comment: That was so simple, I don't know how I missed that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- A string is a 1-dimensional string, but your code indexes it as if it is 2-dimensional, so drop one `[0]`. Note that `[0][0]` will work because the result of the first one is still a string, so in theory you can go on like that and write `user_string[0][0][0][0]`, but it is already what you need to get after the first `[0]`.
- The argument to `count` should not be literal string 'user_character', but the name (without quotes)
- The count should exclude the very first character (which is not part of the string that follows after the first space), so subtract one.

```
user_string = input()
user_character = user_string[0]   # a string has only one dimension

# pass the name (not a literal) and subtract one to ignore the very first character
times = user_string.count(user_character) - 1

print(user_string)
print(user_character)
print(times)
```