# How to determine the number of occurrences of letters in a quote

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to create a small program which will iterate over a quote then return each letter and how many times it features in the quote, but am getting stuck with the for loop portion of the code.

So far this is what I have:

```
string = "All that glitters is not gold."

#create a list containing the English alphabet (lower case)
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

#Create a variable to store the frequency of each letter & assign it a value of zero
i = 0

#if a letter in the string matches a letter in the alphabet
#increase the value of the frequency variable by one
for i in string:
    if i in letters:
      i += 1
    
#print the letter in the alphabet list followed by a colon and the value of the frequency variable
print(" : ".format(element, i))
```

The comments before each line of code are pseudocode that I have been provided with, any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the built-in `collections.Counter()` function.

Comment: You don't have a separate counter for each letter. You're using the same variable `i` for all the letters.

Comment: You could change `letters` to a dictionary containing counters. Then you increment `letters[i]`.

Comment: @Barmar To be fair, the given instructions look wrong, so somewhat not their fault.

Comment: @KellyBundy What's wrong in the instructions?

Comment: @Woodford That question is about counting occurrences of a specific character, not all characters.

Comment: @Barmar Well, how do make sense of *"Create a variable to store the frequency of each letter & assign it a value of zero"*? That does sound like `i = 0`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I didn't realize the comments were the instructions.

Comment: @Barmar Looks like you're not the only one, as all four answers either modified or deleted them :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `collections.Counter()` as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said:

```py
# Convert the quote to lowercase to make the counting case-insensitive
quote = quote.lower()

# Use Counter to count frequencies
letter_counts = Counter(quote)

# Iterate through letters
for letter in letters:
    count = letter_counts[letter]
    print(f"{letter} : {count}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that leverages `collections.Counter.most_common` to return the count of all letters (and punctuation) in a given string:

```
from collections import Counter

string = "All that glitters is not gold."


def count_letters(string: str) -> int:
    return Counter(string.lower()).most_common()


print(count_letters(string))
# => [(' ', 5), ('t', 5), ('l', 4), ('a', 2), ('g', 2), ('i', 2), ('s', 2), ('o', 2), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('r', 1), ('n', 1), ('d', 1), ('.', 1)]
```

Note that using `str.lower()` here makes the result case-insensitive, so `a` == `A`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the entire alphabet, then we'll use your letters list as a starting point. Note that this is different from using collections.counter() because that strategy does not produce a result with every letter in your alphabet list.

```
    string = "All that glitters is not gold."
    
    #create a list containing the English alphabet (lower case)
    letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    
    # init the letter counts dictionary to all zeros for all the letters in the alphabet
    letterCounts = dict()
    for letter in letters:
        letterCounts[letter] = 0
    
    
    #if a letter in the string matches a letter in the alphabet
    #increase the value of the frequency variable by one
    for c in string:
#       the try/except handles spaces and other non-letter characters
        try:
            letterCounts[c.lower()] += 1
        except:
            pass
    print(letterCounts)
```

Comment: you can use `dict.fromkeys()` instead of the `for` loop to initialize the dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

python

## Here is a possible way to write the program using a dictionary to store the frequencies of each letter

string = "All that glitters is not gold."

## create a list containing the English alphabet (lower case)

letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

## create an empty dictionary to store the frequencies of each letter

freq = {}

## loop through each letter in the string

for i in string:
# if the letter is in the alphabet list
if i in letters:
# if the letter is already in the dictionary, increment its frequency by one
if i in freq:
freq[i] += 1
# otherwise, add the letter to the dictionary with a frequency of one
else:
freq[i] = 1

## loop through each letter in the alphabet list

for j in letters:
# if the letter is in the dictionary, print its frequency
if j in freq:
print(j, ": ", freq[j])
# otherwise, print zero
else:
print(j, ": ", 0)

Comment: My eyes! Please use proper code formatting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting